# Angular App not running because of localization

Tags: angular, angular-localize

I have an application which was working till a few days back. The application uses localization. Everything looked perfect. Suddenly it stopped working and started giving me this error.

```
Uncaught Error: It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n.
Angular 9 introduced a global `$localize()` function that needs to be loaded.
Please run `ng add @angular/localize` from the Angular CLI.
(For non-CLI projects, add `import '@angular/localize/init';` to your `polyfills.ts` file.
For server-side rendering applications add the import to your `main.server.ts` file.)
    at push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js._global.$localize (core.js:32666:1)
    at Module../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm5/ng-bootstrap.js (ng-bootstrap.js:70:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84:1)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:9:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84:1)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84:1)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:15:35)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
```

I am not sure whether I upgraded the angular cli or not. But once I started getting this error, i uninstalled the angular cli and installed the latest version. But of no use.

Tried executing  `ng add @angular/localize`

```
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
An unhandled exception occurred: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@7.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@9.1.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"9.1.11" from @angular/forms@9.1.11
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^9.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"9.1.11" from @angular/platform-browser@9.1.11
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"9.1.11" from @angular/forms@9.1.11
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       @angular/forms@"^9.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"9.1.11" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.11
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^9.0.6" from angular-datatables@9.0.2     
npm ERR!       node_modules/angular-datatables
npm ERR!         angular-datatables@"^9.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/router, angular-datatables, the root project)
npm ERR!   9 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^10.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@7.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^7.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@10.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^10.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@7.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^7.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Shah Jahan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.  

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shah Jahan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-30T07_47_17_303Z-debug-0.log
Package install failed, see above.
See "C:\Users\SHAHJA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-fYNTDv\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The log file generated is as follows:

```
[error] Error: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@7.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@9.1.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"9.1.11" from @angular/forms@9.1.11
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^9.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"9.1.11" from @angular/platform-browser@9.1.11
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"9.1.11" from @angular/forms@9.1.11
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       @angular/forms@"^9.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"9.1.11" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.11
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^9.0.6" from angular-datatables@9.0.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/angular-datatables
npm ERR!         angular-datatables@"^9.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/router, angular-datatables, the root project)
npm ERR!   9 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^10.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@7.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^7.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@10.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^10.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@7.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^7.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Shah Jahan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shah Jahan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-30T07_47_17_303Z-debug-0.log
Package install failed, see above.
    at Object.installPackage (C:\Devs\Projects\LibMan\LibManWeb\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\install-package.js:39:15)
    at AddCommand.run (C:\Devs\Projects\LibMan\LibManWeb\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\add-impl.js:148:31)
    at async AddCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Devs\Projects\LibMan\LibManWeb\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:134:28)
    at async Object.runCommand (C:\Devs\Projects\LibMan\LibManWeb\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:201:24)
    at async default_1 (C:\Devs\Projects\LibMan\LibManWeb\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:62:31)
```

Can anyone help pls?

Comment: Could you please share your code repository or something?

Comment: @HaseebAhmed any particular file?

Comment: Ideally a Stackblitz to take a look at complete configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that it is trying to install the incorrect version of `@angular/localize`. It should be installing `9.1.11`. Update your `package.json` to include that version and then run `npm install`. You may need to delete the `node_modules` folder first as it may have already installed the incorrect file dependencies.

Note that all `@angular/xxx` packages are versioned so that the first number matches the angular version you are running. i.e. `@angular/localize : 9.1.11` we know it is for Angular 9.

Comment: It worked!!! but the moment I run it from vs code the same problem occurs.. not sure why it only happens when i run it from the vs code. It looks like vs code is updating some of the files and from then it shows the error... strange!!

Comment: Potentially you have other dependency mismatches that vs code is picking up on. There are cases for instance where package `A:1.0` might need `C:1.0`, but then package `B:1.0` needs `C:2.0` and then sometimes package `A`  will throw an error complaining about conflicts because it can't use `C:2.0` - like in your error message above. (if that makes sense)